global variables get different values (web / terminal)
While learning php I came across the following problem.
I don’t understand why I get different values ​​on my local site and in the terminal when I run the following code:
function scopeTest(): int  
{  
    global $a;  
    return $a = 15;  
}  
  
scopeTest();  
echo $a;

terminal: 15
web: warning: Undefined variable $a
When trying to change a global variable through functions, I encountered the same problem.
$a = 1;
function scopeTest(): int
{
    global $a;
    return $a += 4;
}

scopeTest();
echo $a;


terminal: 5
web: 1
I use:

php: 8.3
localserver: php -S


Scope is not different between cli and web. There is something else at play here, I don't see how these web examples could possibly produce the indicated output. The output you're showing is what you would get if the function was never called, perhaps because of something like nginx's open_file_cache. In any case, I wouldn't fret over it too much, as you should generally avoid the use of globals completely.

Both examples you've provided work just fine. But the real lesson should be that "globals can and will cause unexpected things to happen, and are best avoided if at all possible".

I just tried the first one on my webserver, it worked fine.

I used both the built-in php server (php -S localhost:80) and Lamp. Everywhere I received similar values. Yes, indeed, the behavior is as if the function was not called.

Try adding var_dump($a) as the second line in your scopeTest() function to see if the problem is that scopeTest() is not called or $a is not defined. As @Sammitch suggested, global variables are not the best option as using them can result in unpredictable behaviour. Also, your scopeTest() returns $a to nowhere. I will post an example for you.

Please try the following code to see what result you get:
$a = 1;

function scopeTest()
{
    global $a;
    $a += 4;
}

scopeTest();
echo $a;

Because you are accessing $a as a global variable, there is no need to return the value at the end of your function. An alternative to using a global variable would be this:
$a = 1;

function scopeTest($a): int
{
    $a += 4;
    return $a;
}

$a = scopeTest($a);
echo $a;

